# Laminate Hardwood floor installation

Tags: installation, laminate

I am installing a laminate hardwood floor.  When I hung my drywall I left a half inch gap off the concrete to allow my flooring room to go under the drywall to cover.  My question is, how do I allow for the appropriate gap between my laminate and the wall when it will be under the drywall.  I won't be able to get a spacer in the crack?  Do I need to leave a gap?  Can I try to just let the flooring slide under the drywall with no spacer and try to keep it slightly off the wall?  I'm just not sure how to get the appropriate space.

Comment: How about using a strip of foam as a spacer, stiff enough to give you the placement feedback you need, while squishy enough to allow the flooring to expand?

Answer (score 2):

It is typical that the flooring gap needs to be about 3/8 inch from the wall. Drywall on walls is very often 1/2 inch thick. You could this simply elect to just run the flooring right up to the edge of the drywall without sticking it underneath there.

Comment: That's right and there's no issue with seeing it after the base trim is mounted.